# Previous ajax call not aborting datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

[image]

```
     var oTable;            
      $(document).ready(function() {
            oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "module/parents/calendar/file_proc.php",
                "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {

                                  oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                                    "dataType": 'json',
                                    "type": "GET",
                                    "url": sSource,
                                    "data": aoData,
                                    "success": fnCallback
                                  } );
                                   if (typeof $ !== "undefined" && $.fn.dataTable) {
            var all_settings = $($.fn.dataTable.tables()).DataTable().settings();
            for (var i = 0, settings; (settings = all_settings[i]); ++i) {
                //alert(676);
                if (settings.jqXHR)
                    settings.jqXHR.abort();
            }
        }
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                   { "sWidth": "320px"},
                   { "sWidth": "70px"},
                   { "sWidth": "100px"},
                   { "sWidth": "180px"},                      
                    { "bVisible":    false },                            
                ],                                                          
                "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']]
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I'm using `jquery dataTable` 1.6.2 in my old website. When an user searches for something in the searchbox within datatables plugin,its loading ajax request after each keypress. I have searched google and implemented the code for aborting previous ajax requests but its not working.

[image]

The search field ID html tag is

```
<input id="tt" type="text">
```

Comment: Can I know do you want or not search functionality for DataTable or what ??

Comment: @BasantaMatia I want search feature to be there.Suppose a user types letter 'a' in searchbox,ajax call will start,if he types 'ar',again it will start ajax call.Since the result is too large,its taking too much time to load.So i would like to abort all previous ajax requests during search and only allow the current ajax call

Comment: In that case you can write a jquery function where you can check if textbox value count is more than 3 or 4 then call the search functionality

Comment: @BasantaMatia ok..I dont know if I am correct.How can I write the function outside this function for allowing the search only after the character is 3 or 4,since "sAjaxSource" will be requested after every serach keyword

Comment: @BasantaMatia On page load,I need to call the ajax request so that all datas are loaded,then I need to do filtration .

Comment: Exactly. But I can't see your Textbox id here. How you implement search functonality? I mean you told after you type a string or letter in textbox your ajax calling the Datatable. where is that functionality ?

Comment: @BasantaMatia I have attached the screen shot and added the textbox id also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141318/discussion-between-basanta-matia-and-techy).